# Having issues with Teradatasql python

Tags: python, teradata, pycryptodome

I would like to connect to the Teradata server and I am using the following code:

```
 Import teradata
 Import teradatasql

 Con=teradata.connect( connection string)
```

I have downloaded the teradatasql whl file and used the following command to install it:

```
 Pip install teradatasql-16.20.0.39-py3-none-any.whl
```

I am getting the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycryptodome

I have also downloaded a pyroptosomeme but it is not installing

I appreciate your help

Comment: why are you using the wheel

Comment: I found it on google when I looked for teradatasql

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you download and install from pypi directly:

```
pip install teradatasql
```

When you install directly from pypi then `pip install` automatically downloads and installs any required prerequisite packages such as `pycryptodome`.